# Loading javascript file after click event

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, click

I am trying to load a rich text plugin (NicEdit) AFTER a click event. The plugin has two parts to it:

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

When I try to load the files before the click event as follows, it works

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js', function(jd) {
      // Call custom function defined in script
          bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas()
        });
     $("a").click(function(event));
    });
});
```

However, I need it to load AFTER the click event so it is also applied to the innerHTML page I load.

EDIT

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a').on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.getScript("https://s3.amazonaws.com/RichText-javascript/nicEdit.js",function(){
        $('.answers').load(url);
     });//getscript ends
   });//click handler ends
});//doc ready ends
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a syntax error, change ´.load('+url, function´ by ´.load(url, function()

Answer (score 1):

Try .on()  ...  It supersedes .live() and will run the .click() no matter when the code is loaded, before or after.

```
$(parent).on("click","a", function(ev){

});
```

EDIT --  As RoXon pointed out .. This will only work if bound to a parent.

Comment: what you wrote is incorrect. `$('a').on("click", function(ev){` is not the jounger brother of `.live()` Please take a close look at the DOCS

Comment: @ roXon  As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().  --   Direct Quote --  http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Zak the way you're using the `.on()` will *"replace"* the `.bind()`, while a correct *"replacement"* of `.live()` would be: `$(parent).on("click","a", function(){` . Take care and happy coding.

Comment: @ RoXon -- That I do agree with ..  I will edit my above code accordingly..   Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

i hope there are no typos in your actual code the following should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.getScript("http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js",function(){
         //you can use the loaded js script here in the callback
        $('.innerHTML').load(url, function(response){
             //load calback
        });//load ends
     });//getscript ends
   });//click handler ends
});//doc ready ends
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kv4ZN/1/)

Comment: I tried it that way without the load callback function and it doesn't load the file